# How to systematically find sideways stocks?

Tags: stocks, technical-analysis, historical-analysis

Can someone help me?

I would like to be able to analyse stocks based on their movement.
Optically, by reading the charts, it is very easy to see if a chart is moving sideways. But how can I analyse this systematically?

Is there an indicator which is telling something about the sideway movement of a stock?
Is there a different possible solution?

I have also no problems to use a "developer" solution and to implement my own code around.

I am wondering what the "financial business words" and indicators are named for finding sideway movements.

**Update**

Systematically means: how to analyse the stock values via maths or via Indicators?

Comment: For those trying to follow along, a definition of 'sideways trend': http://www.investopedia.com/terms/s/sidewaystrend.asp

Comment: The definition of a sideway trend is clear, but how can I calculate/math (systematically) it from the stock values? Is there an indicator available? Will update my question on this

Answer (score 1):

You can likely use bollinger band values to programmatically recognize sideways trending stocks. Bollinger band averages expand during periods of volatility and then converge on the matched prices the longer there is little volatility in the asset prices.

Also, look at the bollinger band formula to see if you can glean how that indicator does it, so that you can create something more custom fit to your idea.